# latex line number in algorithm starting with 9?

Tags: algorithms, line-numbering

I feel confused why the line numbers in the algorithm I created all starting with 9?

[image: Line numbers in algorithm all start with 9]

The code is as followed:

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate-2013}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Generating Test Cases} \label{alg1}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
       \Procedure{transition}{$P, testCase, length$}    
          \If{$length+1 \leq maxLength$} \label{max}
            .....
           \EndIf
       \EndProcedure   
     \end{algorithmic}
   \end{algorithm}
```

And the packages I use:

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}    
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep,noitemsep,leftmargin=*, topsep=5pt}    
\usepackage{float}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\newcounter{copyrightbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{theorem}

\end{document}
```

EDIT:

I think it is because of the class sig-alternate-2013 I used. It is the ACM format. Could anybody suggests how to edit that class?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please try to give the minimal working example ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228)) in which your problem occurs. Creating it is the first step in debugging and helps us tremendously in pin-pointing where the issue may lie. In particular it should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please make your into one complete sample document demonstrating the problem.  As it stands put your two blocks in to a standard article documentclass does not produce the described behaviour.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I think it is because of the class sig-alternate-2013 I used. It is the ACM format. Do you have any idea how to change it? Thanks

Comment: I downloaded the class from [this link](https://code.google.com/p/byz-churn/source/browse/trunk/sig-alternate-2013.cls) and, after rearranging your code, I got no 9. Can you please tell what version of the class you're using and modify the code to be a compilable example showing the issue?

Comment: I use the class from the above link as well. It still has this problem. Is it because of texmaker I use? It is Texmaker 3.3.1.

Comment: I have got no problem either.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the package `setspace`. I faced the same problem. Apparently `sig-alternate.cls` and `setspace` does not work together properly.